# Kivymd card button functionality

Tags: python, kivy

I have make a simple app using kivy,kivymd and python. on_release functionality in md card not working,my code snippet below.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

kv = '''
    Screen:

        MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: "280dp", "180dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        ripple_behavior: True
        on_release:print("worked")
'''


class TestCard(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


TestCard().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be careful with the tabs you use in your kv string. First of all you start with a tab before the Screen declaration. Thats not working. Then you have to set tabs after you declare the MDCard to set its attributes. Like this it works for me:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
Screen:

    MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: "280dp", "180dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        ripple_behavior: True
        on_release: print("worked")
'''


class TestCard(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


TestCard().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is python statements don't work in .kv files. Another problem is the indentation. So, just change the indentation and create a method in your TestCard class like this :

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

kv = '''
Screen:
    MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: "280dp", "180dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        ripple_behavior: True
        on_release: app.work()
'''


class TestCard(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def work(self):
        print("worked")


TestCard().run()
```